# model.fit does not take all the samples of X_train

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, lstm

hi I experience a strange problem. I run a model and I expected that fit model take `6783` samples but instead, it takes `212`.

so the model is below. First, as you can see `X_train` must have these values

```
timesteps = len(X_train[0]) 
input_dim = len(X_train[0][0])
n_classes = 6

100
6
6783
```

The model goes like this:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(64, return_sequences=True, recurrent_regularizer=l2(0.0015), input_shape=(timesteps, input_dim)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(LSTM(64, recurrent_regularizer=l2(0.0015), input_shape=(timesteps, input_dim)))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(n_classes, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate = 0.0025), loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

and I fit the model

```
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=50)
```

and I take

```
212/212 [==============================] - 21s 99ms/step - loss: 1.1047 - accuracy: 0.5210
```

any ideas? thank you

**Update:**
I change the batch size to 1 and it takes all the samples. But is this an acceptable behaviour? I use Keras 2.2.4 and TensorFlow 2.2.0

Comment: The 212 is the number of steps (=number of batches). 6783/32=211.96875

Comment: what I know is that the batch size  is the number of windows (in my case) that depicted in the model before it updates its weight. So when I set 32 as batch size I expected model to take 32 windows of data

Comment: You have 212 batches with 32 samples each (except the last batch, which is only 31 samples). Thus there are 212*32 - 1=6783 samples in your training data. What is still unclear?

Comment: yes, i understand what are you saying. When I used TensorFlow 1.15.0 the same experiment took all the samples with 32 batch size. It takes 6783 in every epoch. So after the upgrade, i am seeing this. That the reason I get confused

Comment: I am confused ... is your question answered or not?

Comment: what is an accepted number of batch size?

Comment: Any integer larger 0 works as batch size.

Comment: thanks you. The questions is answered